# How can I use setTimeout to print " Hey " after 2 sec, then "how are you" after 4 sec?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    myResolve("Hey");
  }, 2000);
});

myPromise.then(function(value) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
});

let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    myResolve("How are you");
  }, 4000);
});

myPromise.then(function(value) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Promise</h2>

<p>Wait 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds) for this page to change.</p>

<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

I want my code to print "Hey" after 2 sec. then " how are you " after 4 sec.  I want to use setTimeout with promise since it is a part of the exercise

That is what i code so far but why it doesn't work, it doesn't show any result at all.

Can someone tell me how to do it right?

Comment: Check the console in your browser. It shows an error that needs fixing. Voting to close. One other thing: the 4 seconds start immediately, so you'll want to use 6 seconds for the second event, although probably they would want you to chain the second promise after the first.

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: @derpirscher it shows no error on vs code

Comment: Run it here (I turned your code into a runnable snippet). See the error? You cannot define a variable twice with `let`. Remove the second `let`.

Comment: @trincot  thank you now i see it, and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you defined two times the same variable. You cannot create two variables with the same name. Change the name of the second variable from "myPromise" to, for example, "mySecondPromise".

As it is asynchronous, both setTimeout's would start almost at the same time. So the second setTimeout should have a delay value equal to 6000 (6 seconds) instead of 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Get the promise resolution from the function to call the function again with a new timeout duration and message.

```js
var myFunc = (msg, duration) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(msg)
      resolve(true)
    }, duration)
  })
}

console.log('started logging')
myFunc('Hey', 2000).then(() => {
  myFunc('How are you', 4000)
})
```